# Reading a csv file into csh using awk

Tags: csv, awk, csh

Suppose I have a comma-separated file called 'list.txt' which contains the following:

```
1,fileA
2,fileB
```

I want to read these into a while loop in my csh script, so that I can manipulate the comma separated fields separately. I need to scale this up for any number of lines in the input text file as opposed to the 2 in this example.

```
    #!/bin/csh
    set j=1
    while ($j <= 2)
      set index = "`awk -F"," '{if (NR==$j) print $1}' list.txt`"
      set file = "`awk -F"," '{if (NR==$j) print $2}' list.txt`"
      echo $index
      echo $file
      @ j++
    end
```

So I would expect the output of this to be

```
 1
 fileA
 2
 fileB
```

but in stead I get:

```
1,fileA
1,fileA
2,fileB
2,fileB
```

What am I missing here? If I run an equivalent awk command for any given line in the terminal outside of my csh script, it works as I expect it to.

```
awk -F"," '{if (NR==1) print $1}' list.txt
```

returns

```
1
```

I believe in the csh script the trouble is to do with the double inverted commas specifying the delimiter, which means something else in csh, but I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need the quotes in `-F","`?  That looks like the source of confusion and I think `awk -F,` would work instead.

Comment: @ParthaLal Both these should work.

Comment: If I remove the quotes around the comma, I still get the same output as before.

Comment: Don't write csh scripts. Google "csh why not".

Comment: I did end up googling that already, and it would seem like this sort of confusion with quotations is one of the top reasons not to use csh scripts. It sounds like I'd be better off calling the command-line functions I need from with Python etc. Thanks.

Comment: Python??? All UNIX systems come with an excellent text manipulation tool named `AWK`. No need for anything else just to manipulate text and if you do need to do something else (e.g. create/remove files or start/stop processes), well, that's what the rest of shell is for.

Comment: Yes, and using `awk` within my shell is what the question is about.

Comment: Right, so just stick with that but use a shell that is intended for scripting, e.g. bash, no need to go off and do something completely different like install Python or some other non-standard (for UNIX) tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do what you've told us about so far using any awk and a shell that supports arrays, e.g. bash:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
1
fileA
2
fileB

$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(awk -F, -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file) )

$ echo "${arr[0]}"
1
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
fileA
$ echo "${arr[2]}"
2
$ echo "${arr[3]}"
fileB
```

Now, if you tell us what it is you want to DO with the awk output we can provide guidance.

To be clear, the echos above are NOT part of any proposed solution, they are just to show an array was populated. Here's the same in a loop if you prefer (I added some surrounding `<` `>` chars in the echos just to make it clear what the echos are doing vs the awk):

```
$ cat tst.sh
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(awk -F, -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file) )
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "< $i >"
done

$ ./tst.sh
< 1 >
< fileA >
< 2 >
< fileB >
```

but it's not clear any of that is useful. This is much more likely to be what you want instead:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file | xargs -I {} -n1 echo "<" {} ">"
< 1 >
< fileA >
< 2 >
< fileB >
```

Again, until you show us what you want to do with the contents of your input file, we can't help you figure out how to implement a solution.

Given what you just stated in a  comment about wanting to run a command named `gausmooth` with args that include file names generated from your input file, here's one way to do that (remove the echo to execute the command instead of just printing it):

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk -F, '{print $2$1}' file |
xargs -I {} echo gausmooth in="/home/Documents/{}" out="/home/Documents/gs_{}"

$ ./tst.sh
gausmooth in=/home/Documents/fileA1 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileA1
gausmooth in=/home/Documents/fileB2 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileB2
```

Again - if that's not what you want, tell us the rest of the story.

Given your new, new requirements this may be what you want:

```
$ cat file
fileA1,fileA2
fileB1,fileB2
$
$ while IFS=, read -r in1 in2
do
    echo gausmooth in1="/home/Documents/$in1" in2="/home/Documents/$in2" out="/home/Documents/gs_${in1%%[0-9]*}"
done < file
gausmooth in1=/home/Documents/fileA1 in2=/home/Documents/fileA2 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileA
gausmooth in1=/home/Documents/fileB1 in2=/home/Documents/fileB2 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileB
```

As I mentioned in a different comment the usual advice is to avoid shell loops in general but I use them sometimes for simplicity/clarity when I have control over the input and it is easily constrained so that's what I've done in this case. The assumptions are that none of your file names contain commas or newlines and that the name of the `out` file can be created by stripping trailing digits off the first `in` file.

Comment: I have a host of simple command-line routines I want to run on some files which are listed in the text file, and the variables I'm reading in will make up part of the pathname for the input and output. This way works as well, thanks.

Comment: That's excellent, and works exactly as I require, with a bit of additional learning for me. Again, I described the problem slightly too vaguely. The input file reads e.g. `fileA1,fileA2` on line 1, and `fileB1,fileB2` on line 2 and so on. From your example, then, I simply alter the `$2$1` to `$1`, and the job is done. Finally, suppose I want to use both variables in the same line: `gausmooth in1=/home/Documents/fileA1 in2=/home/Documents/fileA2 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileA`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you goal is, but you can do:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file
1
fileA
2
fileB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, if your interest is `awk`

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat infile
1,fileA
2,fileB

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -F, '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n" infile
1
fileA
2
fileB

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk 'gsub(/,/,"\n")+1' infile
1
fileA
2
fileB
```

Comment: Well, the point is that I need to read the fields into variables so I can do other things with them. awk works as I expect on the command line, but it's the particular csh script instance that is the trouble. By the sounds of it, I'd better go about this from within Python anyway, since csh has its problems.

Answer (score -1):

The solution in this case, was to use `cut` in stead of `awk`.

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach LINE ( `cat list.txt` )
  set index = `echo "$LINE" | cut -d',' -f 1`
  set file  = `echo "$LINE" | cut -d',' -f 2`
  echo $index
  echo $file
end
```

which produces the desired output

```
1
fileA
2
fileB
```

and the strings are stored in variables for further use.

Comment: No. No, no, no. You are going about this all wrong. Any time you write a loop in shell to manipulate text you are doing it wrong (google that too) and your lack of quotes, etc. will bite you later if not right away.

Comment: You can cut your front lawn with nail clippers too, doesn't mean it's a good option. I've been programming in UNIX for over 30 years and you are doing this the wrong way and learning very bad habits. Writing scripts incorrectly for trivial jobs like this will stop you from ever learning how to deal with more complicated problems. You're missing the opportunity to learn fundamentals.

Comment: OK then. With that in mind, how would I scale up your IFS/awk example to work for an arbitrary number of lines of the input file? Your solution has as many lines to do the processes I require (in this example, echo) as there are lines in the input text file, which defeats the purpose of the script.

Comment: Those `echo` lines in my answer lines are not part of any solution, they are just showing you that the script above them populates an array. I could have put the echo lines in a loop but since they're just to show that the array is populated and it's only 4 lines I just wrote them explicitly. I certainly wasn't suggesting you would write a line of code for every field of every line of your input file! I can change that to a loop if you like but you still haven't shown us what it is you want to do so I've no idea if populating an array is even the right starting point.

Comment: I just updated my example to show a couple of alternatives for what you might want to do with the output of your awk command, assuming breaking out of awk to do whatever follows is a reasonable approach which it may not be.

Comment: Thanks for updating your example. I see what you mean now - I thought you were advising against the using a loop altogether. I can see why it's better to read in the file before beginning the loop containing the commands. In reality, my list contains pairs of filenames (e.g. the top line is `fileA1, fileA2`), and I'm simply running some command-line tasks on them, e.g.: `gausmooth in=/home/Documents/fileA1 out=/home/Documents/gs_fileA1`. Populating an array would do the job.

Comment: The rule is to never use a shell loop just to manipulate text. Additionally, think very carefully before using a shell loop for anything else. The robust way is to use `xargs` instead of a loop as I show in my final example but I personally find the resulting code a bit more cryptic and so I often do write shell loops when I need to do something more than just manipulate text, but I am very careful about it. In this case, you do NOT need an array at all. Given what you just said, I'll update my answer again to show you. Give me 5 mins...